# Back button is not working propely, why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have dx class in Canvas. It is not working propely. When I am in **Bought** and click back button I am going to **MainMenu**. I want to go **MainMarket** not MainMenu, how can I fix it?

```
public class dx : MonoBehaviour  {

    public GameObject MainMenu;
    public GameObject Login;
    public GameObject MainMarket;
    public GameObject Bought;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Login.activeSelf == true && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            MainMenu.SetActive(true);
            Login.SetActive(false);
            Debug.Log("Login");
            return;
        }
        else if (MainMarket.activeSelf == true && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            MainMenu.SetActive(true);
            MainMarket.SetActive(false);
            Debug.Log("MainMenu");
            return;
        }
        else if (Bought.activeSelf == true && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            MainMarket.SetActive(true);
            Bought.SetActive(false);
            Debug.Log("Bought");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To post code, select it and click the `{}` widget.

Comment: Input.GetKey returns true as long as the key is pressed.  Try Input.GetKeyDown, which only returns true on the first frame the button is pressed and let us know if you still have problems after that.

Comment: @ChrisH thanks it is working, add answer and I will give you +rep.

Comment: This could've very easily been solved by [reading the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html)

Comment: @ned.juliyan you should also consider using a `switch` statement, once you have more than 3 if statements it starts to get a little crowded.

Answer (score 2):

Input.GetKey returns true as long as the key is pressed. Instead use Input.GetKeyDown, which only returns true on the first frame the button is pressed.

Comment: To clarify: Because it's true as long as the key is pressed, you (the user) are incapable of tapping the key for *exactly* one frame, thus `Update()` runs twice (or more) and you escape all the way out of every menu until either there is no where to go or the key is no longer pressed.